# Being clever when copying artifacts with Jenkins and multi-configurations

Tags: jenkins, hudson

Suppose that I have a (fictional) set of projects: FOO and BAR. Both of these projects have some sort of multi-configuration option.

FOO has a matrix on axis `X` which takes values in `{ x1, ..., xn }` (so there are n builds of FOO). BAR has a matrix on axis `Y` which takes values in `{ y1, ..., ym }` (so there are m builds of BAR).

However, BAR needs to copy some artifacts from FOO. It turns out that `Y` is a strictly finer partition than n. For example, `X` might take the values `{ WINDOWS, LINUX }` and `Y` might be `{ WINDOWS_XP, WINDOWS_7, DEBIAN_TESTING, FEDORA }` or whatever.

Is it possible to get BAR to do some sort of table lookup to work out what configuration of FOO it needs when it copies artifacts across? I can easily write a shell script to spit out the mapping, but I can't work out how to invoke it when Jenkins is working out what it needs to copy.

At the moment, a hacky solution is to have two axes on FOO, on for `X` and one for `Y`, and then filter out combinations that don't make sense. But the resulting combination filter is ridiculous and the matrix is very sparse. Yuck.

A solution that I don't like is to parametrise FOO on `Y` instead: this would be a huge waste of compile time. And, worse, the generated artefacts are pretty big, so even if you did some sort of caching, you'd still have to keep unnecessary copies floating around.

Comment: When you say `"FOO is parameterized on variable X"`, are you saying FOO has an **Axis/Matrix** `X` or do you actually mean it has a parameter `X`

Comment: Ah, sorry: I used the wrong phrase. Yes, I mean that FOO has an axis `X` and BAR has an axis `Y` (so there are n build configurations for FOO and m build configurations for BAR)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can't say I fully understand the intricacies if your matrices, but I think I can help you with your actual question

`"I can easily write a shell script to spit out the mapping, but I can't work out how to invoke it when Jenkins is working out what it needs to copy"`

The **Archive the artifacts** and **Copy artifacts from another project** post-build actions can take java style wildcards, like `module/dist/**/*.zip` as well as environment variables/parameters, like `${PARAM}` for the list or artifacts. You can use commas `,` to add more artifacts.

The on-page help for **Copy artifacts from another project** states how to copy artifacts of a specific matrix configuration: `To copy from a particular configuration, enter JOBNAME/AXIS=VALUE`, this is for the `Project Name` attribute. That `project name` attribute can also contain params as `${PARAM}`

So, in your **BAR** job, have a **Copy Artifacts** build step, with `Project Name` being `FOO/X=${mymapping}`. What this will do is: every time a configuration of `BAR` is run, it will copy artifacts only from `FOO` with configuration of `X=${mymapping}`.

Now you need to set the value of `${mymapping}` dynamically every time `BAR` is run. A simple script like this may do the trick:

```
[[ ${Y:0:7} == "WINDOWS" ]] && mymapping=WINDOWS || mymapping=LINUX
```

Finally, you need to use [**EnvInject**](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin) plugin to make this variable available to the rest of the build steps, including the **Copy Artifacts** step.

So, every time `BAR` configuration runs, it will look at its own configuration axis `Y`, and if that axis starts with `WINDOWS`, it will set the `${mymapping}` to `WINDOWS`, else set it to `LINUX`. This `${mymapping}` is then made available to the rest of the build steps. When `Copy Artifacts` build step is executed, it will only copy artifacts from `FOO` where the `X` axis matches `${mymapping}` (i.e. either `WINDOWS` or `LINUX`).

### Full Setup

- Install [**EnvInject**](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin) plugin.
- In **BAR** job configuration, tick `Prepare an environment for the run` (part of EnvInject plugin).
- Make sure both checkboxes for keeping existing variables are checked.
- In `Script Content` copy your script:
  `[[ ${Y:0:7} == "WINDOWS" ]] && mymapping=WINDOWS || mymapping=LINUX`
- Under **Build** steps, configure **Copy Artifacts** build step.
- Set **Project name** parameter to `FOO/X=${mymapping}`
- Configure the rest as usual.

Comment: That's really helpful, thank you. I understood how to use environment variables and JOBNAME/AXIS=VALUE, but didn't know about EnvInject. The only wrinkle is that the mapping is rather more complicated than the dummy LINUX/WINDOWS example I gave (in fact, it's from chip name to machine architecture). Is there any way to run a shell script that's in one of the build trees? Ideally, I'd run something like "FOO/scripts/get-X $Y" in the FOO tree that I was about to build. Is something like that possible?

Comment: Wow, you read my reply faster than it took me to proof read it after posting :). EnvInject is quite flexible and allows to either run a script or supply a properties file. As long as you can write some algorithm to determine the required axis from `FOO`, you should be able to use this. Also, don't forget that you can have multiple `Copy Artifact` build steps, for some really complex scenarios and can set them as optional too.

Comment: Right, I need to go and read the EnvInject documentation more carefully then. What I was worried about was how to get the path to the script that I want to run (presumably in the FOO build tree). But maybe there's a Jenkins variable that I can use for that: I'll go and start reading.

Comment: If you are triggering `BAR` from `FOO` through promotions, you can reference back to `FOO` through variables like [`PROMOTED_JOB_NAME`](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Promoted+Builds+Plugin). Then, you can construct an absolute path on the filesystem to the scripts under `FOO`. Of course it would be better is the scripts actually existed in `BAR`. Good luck

Comment: I've got it working! :-) If anyone else wants to do this, the trick is to add two build steps. The first is a shell command that should produce a properties file. This performs the "mapping" step to work out the correct value of `X` in the situation above. It can run a script in BAR's repository. The second step is to use EnvInject to "Inject environment variables" using the resulting properties file. Then you put the "Copy artifacts from another project" steps afterwards and use the shiny new environment variables. Awesome!

Comment: Right, I completely missed the part where `Prepare an environment for the run` is before the SCM checkout