# Jenkins: How to use user defined shell variables when copying artifacts from another project

Tags: jenkins

In my Jenkins configuration I have a conditional step which exports a custom shell variable called "SUFFIX". I want to use this variable in name the of the project from which I am copying artifacts but it says:

```
Unable to find project for artifact copy: myProject${SUFFIX}_release
```

How can I use such a variable or achieve such a behaviour where the project name depends on a job parameter. The job parameter is a boolean value and should stay a boolean value. There should not be a string parameter SUFFIX.

Is this question related: [Being clever when copying artifacts with Jenkins and multi-configurations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22558326/being-clever-when-copying-artifacts-with-jenkins-and-multi-configurations)
Do I need the EnvInject plugin to make variables accessible by the Copying artifacts plugin?

Answer (score 1):

Jenkins does not retain environment variable changes between builds or build-steps. This is part of the design, to keep the build environment clean.

You cannot export an environment variable in **Execute Shell** build step, and then use it in **Copy Artifacts** build step. To get around this, you do need [**EnvInject plugin**](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin).

- Instead of exporting your shell environment variable to the Environment, you need to write it to - properties file, in format `param=value`
- Then, using EnvInject build step, load that properties file
- After that, your newly loaded environment variable will be available to all subsequent build/post-build steps, including Copy Artifacts build step.

Comment: I don't get it. There is only one job which copies the artifacts from another job but the other job from which the artifacts come from has nothing to do with triggering or passing any variables to the second job. The second job simply uses its OWN parameter to generate a name and I simply cannot use the Bash syntax ${SUFFIX} for this variable for unknown reason.

Comment: Re-wrote the answer based on your clarification